# How to put a gray overlay on an image in CSS

Tags: css

I'd like to create a website that has a banner on every page with an image that has a gray overlay. In that way, white text on the image becomes more visible.
The result should look exactly like this: http://skoopopweg.weebly.com/programma.html.

I found ways to dull the image, but not to put an overlay on top of it. 
Can anybody help?

This is my code in CSS for this class of images thus far:

```
.img-with-overlay{width:100%; position:relative;}
```

And in html:

```
<img class="img-with-overlay" src="img1.jpg" />
```

Comment: Any overlay would dull the text in the image too, unless you meant you were putting the text in the overlay

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: check this for help. https://jsfiddle.net/n5qfa/90/

Comment: The text is in a separate class, I'm looking for a piece of code that only affects the layout of the images.

Answer (score 16):

I found this to work well.

```css
#your-img-id {
   filter: brightness(30%);
}
```

Not quite as flexible but very simple for this use case.

Answer (score 10):

the idea:

- use a div as a wrapper with `position: relative`
- use a div as an overlay with `position: absolute` and `background-color` (you can change the first 3 values to set RGB color and the 4rth for the opacity level)

```css
.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
}

.img-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(128,128,128,0.75);
}

.img-wrapper img {width: 100%;}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <div class="img-overlay"></div>
  <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tgogos/CS_comics/master/imgs/106-tech-debt.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.image_div{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.image_div img{
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}

.image_div .img_overlay{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="image_div">
  <img src="http://cl.jroo.me/z3/q/R/R/d/a.aaa-Unique-Nature-Beautiful-smal.jpg">
  <div class="img_overlay">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0cbvje5L/)

Is this the same that you are looking for?

Hope this helps.

Comment: we have some css rules for this specific task.